# Save Image Using Observer Or Model

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I want to upload and save image using `observer` or `model`.
How can I do that?

```
$imageAdapter = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();

$uploader->addValidateCallback($po_file, $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
$mediaDirectory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
$result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('customer/senapro'));
$a= $result['file'];
print_r($a);
```

**this code not working**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are uploading the image from a Form, you can save the image using a controller:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Upload extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{     
   protected $_fileUploaderFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        Action\Context $context

    ) {

        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(){

        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);

        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);

        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

        $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)

        ->getAbsolutePath('images/');

        $uploader->save($path);

    }
}
```

If you want to reuse the code, you can move this to a model and call it in your controller.

Comment: thanks for answer but i am using payment form so i cant create controller because its payment form guide me

Comment: So must be must be submitting some form , you can use the code in that action or create a ajax image uploader

Comment: ajax image uploader?

Comment: Yes as soon as someone selects a image it is uploaded and saved against your quote , I am not sure what is your use case , why are you uploading image against a payment method so i can't suggest a optimal solution but above code works for image upload

Comment: can you give any tutorial

Comment: http://hkpatel201.blogspot.com/2018/05/magento2-upload-files.html i have not tried the soultion and you can do a google search for more

Comment: my case is i am creating po number payment method where i create 2 fields 1 is text box and other is file upload